# Delphi/FireMonkey: Cannot set Android camera to work

Tags: android, delphi, camera, firemonkey

I'm trying to reproduce the AccessCameraApp.dproj app but it does not work for the TakePhotoFromCameraAction1, giving me the following error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser
android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference.

The odd thing is that the Library button works perfectly...

The form looks like this:
[Form1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNtYZ.png)

### and the code is as follows:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants, System.Permissions,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls, System.Actions,
  FMX.ActnList, FMX.StdActns, FMX.MediaLibrary.Actions, FMX.Objects, FMX.Graphics,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Image1: TImage;
    Button1: TButton;
    ActionList1: TActionList;
    Button2: TButton;
    TakePhotoFromLibraryAction1: TTakePhotoFromLibraryAction;
    TakePhotoFromCameraAction1: TTakePhotoFromCameraAction;
    procedure TakePhotoFromCameraAction1DidFinishTaking(Image: TBitmap);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);

  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure DisplayRationale(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TArray<string>; const APostRationaleProc: TProc);
    procedure TakePicturePermissionRequestResult(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TArray<string>; const AGrantResults: TArray<TPermissionStatus>);

  private const
    PermissionCamera = 'android.permission.CAMERA';
    PermissionReadExternalStorage = 'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE';
    PermissionWriteExternalStorage = 'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE';

  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   TAG := 1;
   PermissionsService.RequestPermissions([PermissionCamera, PermissionReadExternalStorage, PermissionWriteExternalStorage], TakePicturePermissionRequestResult, DisplayRationale);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   TAG := 2;
   PermissionsService.RequestPermissions([PermissionCamera, PermissionReadExternalStorage, PermissionWriteExternalStorage], TakePicturePermissionRequestResult, DisplayRationale);
end;

procedure TForm1.DisplayRationale(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TArray<string>; const APostRationaleProc: TProc);
begin
   APostRationaleProc;
end;

procedure TForm1.TakePicturePermissionRequestResult(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TArray<string>; const AGrantResults: TArray<TPermissionStatus>);
begin
   if (Length(AGrantResults) = 3) and (AGrantResults[0] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) and (AGrantResults[1] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) and (AGrantResults[2] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) then
   begin
      if TAG = 1
      then TakePhotoFromCameraAction1.Execute
      else TakePhotoFromLibraryAction1.Execute;
   end
   else
      ShowMessage('Cannot take a photo because the required permissions are not all granted');
end;

procedure TForm1.TakePhotoFromCameraAction1DidFinishTaking(Image: TBitmap);
begin
   Image1.Bitmap := Image;
end;


end.
```

---

Answer (score 2):

Check that the Project Options > Entitlements List > Secure File Sharing option is set to true.
Thanks to Dave Nottage